# Can I pass a value into a SQL trigger through a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to create a history table for actions done inside the database, the easiest way i thought was to create a history table that was updated through a trigger on each table modified.

I would like to also include a userId so I can identify who changed it as well, but when i do my inserts/delete statements etc, I would also need to add in the userId (which kinda has no relevance to the operation), in order to use the history table as i described.

So is there a way to just put the userId into a SQL statement? Or should I just actually do the history table as a separate query after doing my insert / delete statements, rather than using a trigger

Thanks in advance

Grant

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Apologies, probably should have put that i was using mysql

Answer (score 0):

It will be the best practices to add user column in main table which we can easily use in trigger to inserts/delete/update in  history table.

Comment: I don't know if i want to do that? since the user column will generally have no relation to the data stored in that particular table?